# Snowflake network policy are not working for Free Trial

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created network policy to restrict the user by using ALLOWED_IP_LIST only.

```
CREATE NETWORK POLICY Test ALLOWED_IP_LIST = ('103.136.64.120');
```

Question is:

1. I'm using free trial and unable to set network policy through portal
2. If I can create NETWORK POLICY through command prompt, then how we can check/test policy on Web
   3)I tried to execute query on Web, still able to access database(expecting to restrict it for particular IP)

Note: I followed the documents https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-network-policy.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you create a network policy, you need to apply it to either the account or a user. You can use the UI to apply an account-level network policy.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/network-policies.html#modify-an-account-level-network-policy

You can apply a network policy to either the account or a user using SQL to alter the account or user parameter for NETWORK_POLICY:

Account:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-account.html#alter-account

User:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-user.html#alter-user

You may consider testing on a user first (creating an additional one if required) to avoid accidentally locking yourself out from the account.